# How to make random decisions on variables of variables?

Tags: python, random

So we have a school project to make a program  that asks the user whether to pick a random card from a 52 deck or simulate a coin toss - heads or tails. I've got a beta version working but I'm looking into how to make the program more efficient. Basically, the program sets the tuples 'card' and 'coin' to all the possible types, so for coin, heads and tails, and card, the 52 different cards.

The following part of the program sets the variable 'choice' to either card or coin

```
    while choice!='card' and choice!='coin':
            choice=input("Pick a card or toss a coin (card/coin)?: ")
            if choice!="card" and choice!="coin":
                print("Please enter either 'card' or 'coin'...")
                time.sleep(2)
```

Next I want to be able to return a value from either tuple depending on the value of 'choice' without using and if statement, something along the following:

```
    print("The ",choice," picked at random is... ",random.choice("Either card, or coin"),"!")
```

How would I do this? Thanks, Brandon.

Full program:

```
#importing modules used in program
import time
import random

#creating duples for possible cards and coins
cards=["Ace of spades","King of spades","Queen of spades","Jack of spades","10 of spades","9 of spades","8 of spades","7 of spades","6 of spades","5 of spades","4 of spades","3 of spades","2 of spades","Ace of diamonds","King of diamonds","Queen of diamonds","Jack of diamonds","10 of diamonds","9 of diamonds","8 of diamonds","7 of diamonds","6 of diamonds","5 of diamonds","4 of diamonds","3 of diamonds","2 of diamonds","Ace of clubs","King of clubs","Queen of clubs","Jack of clubs","10 of clubs","9 of clubs","8 of clubs","7 of clubs","6 of clubs","5 of clubs","4 of clubs","3 of clubs","2 of clubs","Ace of hearts","King of hearts","Queen of hearts","Jack of hearts","10 of hearts","9 of hearts","8 of hearts","7 of hearts","6 of hearts","5 of hearts","4 of hearts","3 of hearts","2 of hearts"]
coin=["Heads","Tails"]

#setting variable 'repeat' to 'y' to start the mainloop of the program
repeat="y"
while repeat=="y":

    #blanking the repeat and choice variables so they can be reset later
    repeat=""
    choice=""

    #won't allow the user to continue until either 'card' or 'coin' is entered
    while choice!='card' and choice!='coin':
        choice=input("Pick a card or toss a coin (card/coin)?: ")
        if choice!="card" and choice!="coin":
            print("Please enter either 'card' or 'coin'...")
            time.sleep(2)


    print("The ",choice," picked at random is... ",random.choice(card),"!")


    #won't allow the user to continue until either 'y' or 'n' is entered
    while repeat!="y" and repeat!="n":
        repeat=input("Go again..? (y/n): ")
        if repeat!="y" and repeat!="n":
            print("Please enter either 'y' for yes or 'n' for no...")
            time.sleep(2)

#ending of the program
print("Goodbye!")
time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: I think you would be better off using a simple if check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to have a dictionary of tuples:

```
items = { 'coin': coin,
          'card': cards }
```

Then, after `choice` has been set properly by your `while` loop, use the word provided by the user as the key to select from the dictionary the correct list, which can then be passed to `random.choice`:

```
print("The ", choice, " picked at random is ...", random.choice(items[choice]))
```

Comment: this will crash as soon as any word other than coin or card is entered

Comment: I'm assuming this is used after the given `while` statement, which ensures that `choice` is either `card` or `coin`.

Comment: Yep, I missed the `!=` in the code. Hard to see sandwiched together

Answer (score 0):

I'm for sure if this is what you're asking, but if the tuple you're talking about is this `('coin', 'card')`, then you can do the following:

```
import random

test = ('coin', 'card')
test[random.randint(0, 1)]
```

That will randomly select one of the two choices.

Comment: Not quite what i was asking for